# QGIS - Setting the CRS of a CSV file

Tags: qgis

I ran into an issue when trying to complete an exercise in David Abernathy’s book “Using Geodata & Geolocation in the Social Sciences” (Chapter 11).

The exercise is straight forward: load a shapefile of counties in California and overlay it with the location of all sites being regulated or monitored by the EPA.

Shapefile of Counties in CA:
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2013/cb_2013_us_county_5m.zip

CSV file containing lat/long coordinates of EPA sites:
https://www3.epa.gov/enviro/html/fii/downloads/state_files/state_single_ca.zip

Per the exercise, the map should be reprojected using CRS “EPSG: 3310, NAD 83 / California Albers”.  To complete this task, I did the following:

1)  Imported shapefile and saved a copy that is limited to just California ("STATEFP"  =  '06') using CRS “EPSG: 3310”.  This worked as planned.
2)  Imported the CSV file by specifying the X/Y coordinates as LONGITUDE83/LATITUDE83 and selecting “EPSG: 3310” for the CRS

This results in the following screenshot.  At first, all the EPA locations appear to be a single dot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR1aA.png)

But after zooming in further, the EPA locations are actually nested as a “sub-map” of California.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAWM7.png)

In order to make things work properly, I ended up reloading the CSV file using CRS “EPSG: 4269, NAD 83” (without the California Albers option).  Given that a file of lat/long coordinates doesn't have an inherent projection, I don’t understand why my approach outlined above didn’t work.  It appears that when QGIS is asking for the CRS, it’s actually asking for the datum.  Is this true? 
 Are there any experts who could weigh in and explain the nuances associated with picking a CRS when importing a text file of coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Because your csv file was in latitude and longitude you have to tell qgis that (because there is no explicit crs). The way you do this is to set the projection to epsg:4326 (or possibly 4269 if you are sure it is on the NAD datum).

QGIS can then make use of the projection to change your points into the project projection and make everything line up on screen.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this mean choosing "EPSG: 3310, NAD 83 / California Albers” does not work by design?  Or put differently, can the user not freely choose any CRS from the pop-up window?

Comment: You *can* pick any projection you like but you are telling QGIS that your data is in **that** projection so you shouldn't lie to it. QGIS will then reproject your points to the projection you have set fo your map.

Comment: Given that a list of coordinates isn't already associated with a projection (unlike a shapefile), I'm not sure how a user could "lie" to QGIS.  Is it possible that when specifying a CRS for a list of lat/long coordinates, the user must pick a geographic coordinate system and not a projected coordinate system?

Comment: The list of coordinates is in a projection and if you pick a different projection, then QGIS will believe you and become confused.